# Biblatex 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Texlive 2016

Tags: biblatex, lyx, texlive, biber, ubuntu

I installed `Tex Live 2016` on `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS` using

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Now References are not working. When I use `biber` in `LYX 2.2.2`, I get the following error:

> Biber error: Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.1, expected
>   version 3.2.

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra biber
```

it says,

> texlive-bibtex-extra is already the newest version
>   (2016.20160520-1~ubuntu16.04.1york1). biber is already the newest
>   version (2.6.0-0york1~16.04).

I guess, I have old version of `Biblatex`. I could not figure out how to install the latest version of `Biblatex`. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What does `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` at the Terminal report? It's possible you've got a 'local' file installation that's over-riding the system one. (I assume that the versions do match  from the Ubuntu repos.)

Comment: The `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` gives `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty`.

Comment: Thanks @JosephWright for your comment and concern in my problem. The `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` gives `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty`.

Comment: Present version of biblatex is `3.5`.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard for your comment. Please [See her](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/biblatex-3.6/).

Comment: @MYaseen208 OK, that sounds like the 'right' location. What does `biber version: 2.6` given, and if you do ``less `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` `` what version is shown in the file? (There should be a line something like `\def\abx@version{3.6}` near the start.)

Comment: @MYaseen208: You're right. I was mistaken  by a typo in the documentation: its title specifies version `3.5`, while .log files specify version `3.6`. Corresponding `biber` version  is `2.6`.

Comment: @JosephWright, In the output of `less 'kpsewhich biblatex.sty'` there is line with `\def\abx@version{3.4}`.

Comment: @JosephWright, Please any help to figure out my problem.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I don't use Ubuntu routinely and the version I do have available isn't the one you are using. So I'm not best-placed to help here. I wonder if you need to update your `biblatex` Ubuntu package, but I can't be sure (as I say, I don't have a system I can check with). (From the question it sounds like things _should_ be up-to-date, which is why I think a 'check' system is needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` to get `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.st‌​y`.
2. [From SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/) download `biber v.2.6`.
3. [From SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/) download `biblatex v.3.6`
4. Create two temp dirs: `mkdir tempbb && mkdir tempbl`
5. Uncompress `biber-cygwin64.tar.gz` and `biblatex-3.6.tds.tgz` to the temp directories:

   ```
   tar -zxvf biber-cygwin64.tar.gz -C tempbb/
   tar -zxvf biblatex-3.6.tds.tgz -C tempbl/
   ```
6. Move the contents of the files in the `tempbl` temp directory to `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/` thus:

   ```
   sudo rsync -azvv tempbl/ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/
   ```
7. Move the `biber` bin from your temp directory to  `/usr/share/texlive/` thus:

   ```
   sudo rsync -azvv tempbl/ /usr/share/texlive/
   ```
8. Run `mktexlsr`
9. Test that everything is working fine.